# Monthly graph: barWidth not correct when time mode in Flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a monthly graph with some data. The data is shown by bars (1 month/bar).

I'm trying to set the barWidth according to the month.

The barWidth is calculated for each month:

- January : `60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 1000`
- February: `60 * 60 * 24 * 28 * 1000`
- March   : `60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 1000`

  etc...

But unfortunately the result is not as expected...

I have space between January and February, March starts too early and his bar is on the bar of February.

Here is some code that you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ2Y/2/

Do you have an idea how to show a correct bar for each month?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could add a style to the xaxis and remove the align. Also I specified a tick array and month name format.

```
#placeholder .tickLabel {margin-left: 15%;}

var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ m1, m2, m3], {
xaxis : {
    mode          : "time",

    ticks: [1356998400000, 1359676800000, 1362096000000 ],
    timeformat: "%b"

},
series : {
    bars: {
        show: true,


        fillColor : { colors : ["#32b9ff", "#2b78a0"] }
    }
}
});
```

Link to fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ2Y/3/